# Sails.js body-parser middleware

Tags: node.js, sails.js, body-parser

I was trying to write POST api in `Sails.js` and was wondering if I need to explicitly use body-parser to parse POST request bodies. [This](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Middleware) documentation says,

> Sails comes bundled with a suite of conventional HTTP middleware, ready to use. You can, of course, disable, override, rearrange, or append to it, but the pre-installed stack is perfectly acceptable for most apps in development or production.

`body-parser` is included in their conventional defaults. Does this mean that `Sails.js` uses body-parser by default and I don't need to do anything to use it? If not, then what should I need to do to use body-parser in my app?

Answer (score 2):

The same documentation page that you referenced has a list of middleware that Sails uses. As you can see, `bodyParser` is one of them. So no, you don't need to add anything to your app.
In your Sails controllers you can get the request body through `req.body`.